# i have headers separately, how to import it to informatica target

Tags: informatica

I have source and target in an informatica powercenter developer. I heed some other header name to be imported in the target file automatically without any manual entry. How can I import customized headers to informatica target.

Comment: If you open a session, switch to _Mapping_ tab and click a target, there are two properties - _Header Options_ and _Header Command_. These may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is,
In session command, there is an option called user defined headers. Type **echo** followed by column name separated by comma delimited

```
echo A, B, C
```

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

You can use a header command in the session configuration for the target, I haven't used it, and couldn't find any documentation on it (i.e. what is possible and how, whether parameters can be used or not, etc.).  I did test using (on Windows) an ECHO command to output its text to the header row, but it didn't seem to recognize parameters.

Or you can try to include the header as the first data output row.  That means your output will have to be all string types and length restrictions may compound the issue.

Or you can try using two mappings, one that truncates the files and writes the header and one which outputs the data specifying append in the session.  You may need two target definitions pointing to the same files.  I don't know if the second mapping would attempt to load the existing data (i.e. typecheck), in which case it might throw an error if it didn't match.

Other options may be possible, we don't do much with flat files.

Comment: I have used it. The parameters used should be in use by the session or be defined as workflow variables. Another option to use would be to use a presession command to add header and use append it exists file option to add data after the header has been added.